# How to import web content into a Windows form using VB.Net?

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to import various parts of the webpage by string match. Can some one tell me how I do this as this may also involve HTML. For example consider that I import the headlines from the source of "news.google.com" or "www.yahoo.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to go to a specific website and look for specific data (e.g. a screen scraper).

You can accomplish this easily using the web browser object "axWebBrowser".  If you want something a little more raw, you can use the System.Net.WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague to answer with any real accuracy. However, since you mentioned 'headlines', I suggest you look up how to implement RSS feeds. There's an [example here](http://www.philweber.com/articles/easy_rss_in_vbnet.htm).

If you need to parse HTML, you can look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.